# Sklearn KNeighborsClassifier gives different results when using KNeighborsTransformer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to get my head around how to use `KNeighborsTransformer` correctly, so I am using the Iris dataset to test it.
However, I find that when I use `KNeighborsTransformer` before the `KNeighborsClassifier` I get different results than using `KNeighborsClassifier` directly.

When I plot the decision boundaries, they are similar, but different.
[image: Using only KNeighborsClassifier]
[image: Using KNeighborsTransformer and then KNeighborsClassifier]

I have given the metric and weights mode explicitly, so that cannot be the problem.

Why do I get this difference?
Does it have something to do with whether they count a point as its own nearest neighbour?
Or does it have something to do with the `metric='precomputed'`?

Below is the code I use to consider the two classifiers.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline


# import data 
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# We only take the first two features. 
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target

n_neighbors = 15

knn_metric = 'minkowski'
knn_mode = 'distance'

# With estimator with KNeighborsTransformer
estimator = make_pipeline(
    neighbors.KNeighborsTransformer(
        n_neighbors = n_neighbors + 1, # one extra neighbor should already be computed when mode == 'distance'. But also the extra neighbour should be filtered by the following KNeighborsClassifier
        metric = knn_metric,
        mode = knn_mode),
    neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(
        n_neighbors=n_neighbors, metric='precomputed'))

estimator.fit(X, y)
print(estimator.score(X, y)) # 0.82


# with just KNeighborsClassifier

clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(
    n_neighbors, 
    weights = knn_mode,
    metric = knn_metric)
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.score(X, y)) # 0.9266666666666666
```

Comment: That is too much code. Can you minimize it? Do we need the stuff with plotting, for example?

Comment: The plotting was so that people could run it themselves and see the difference, but I will put up pictures instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline approach uses the default uniform vote, but your direct approach uses the distance-weighted vote.  Making them match (either both distance or both uniform) almost makes the behavior match; the seeming remaining difference is in tie-breaking of nearest neighbors; I'm not sure yet why the tie-breaking is happening differently in the two cases, but it's likely not such a big issue with more realistic datasets.

Comment: Thank you!
I don't know why, but I thought when I put the mode to 'distance' on the `KNeighborsTransformer` it would carry over to the `KNeighborsClassifier`. When I set the weights in `KNeighborsClassifier` to 'distance' I no longer see a difference :)